# Get current pinned section of UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview

What is the most accurate way to get the title or index of the top most section in the UITableView? I don't mean the section at index 0, but the section header that is currently pinned at the top while scrolling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the section at the top of the screen like so:

```
     NSUInteger sectionNumber = [[tableView indexPathForCell:[[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0]] section];
```

But, this method might not be optimal for you because it will get the number will weird when it is in the transition period between two headers. As long as you don't need to know the section during the transition you should be fine.
I hope this is what your looking for,

Comment: What method should I put this in to keep the sectionNumber current?

Comment: Scrollviewdidscroll if you want it to update every time the user scrolls

Comment: you have to check `[tableView visibleCells].count > 0` before accessing its zeroth element

Answer (score 3):

i believe that instead of querying for the visibleCells, it's better to ask for the index paths the following way:

```
NSInteger section = [[[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] firstObject] section];
```

You can use this code in one of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift version**

Use *first* (current pinned) or *last* (last displayed)

```
  if let section:Int = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.section {

      tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: true)

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have your class implement the UIScrollViewDelegate, and implement the following functions.
It will ensure you retrieve section only when tableview stops scrolling.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
{
        // retrieve section here
        section = [[[self.tableview visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0] section];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        // retrieve section here
        section = [[[self.tableview visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0] section];
}
```

Comment: I guess by doing it this way, it prevents the issue of the sections getting confused when they are in transition?

Comment: This throws errors with my custom cell for some reason... ` -[AppointmentCustomCell section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89af850`. All I'm doing is NSLogging the section in the above code you provided.

Comment: This is old but all kinds of wrong because `self.tableView visibleCells` gives the `UITableViewCells` and not `IndexPaths`. After getting indexPaths, then we can do indexPaths[0].section.